# useState hooks usage in reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am using useState hook to set a state variable. but there. was some strange behaviour.

**CASE 1:**

```
const [name, setName] = useState(route.params.name)
```

this is working fine have no problem.

**CASE 2:**

```
const [name] = useState(route.params.name)
```

this is also same.

**CASE 3:**

```
const name = useState(route.params.name)
```

Here is the confusion when I try to access the name it is crashing, when I `console.log(name)` the output was like this.

```
> [{"country_code": "US", "displayName": "Appleseed John",
> "facebook_profile_link": null, "filtered_contact_id": "23033489",
> "hasThumbnail": false, "internationalNumberFormat": "+1 888-555-5512",
> "key": "0undefined2", "mobile_number": "8885555512", "name":
> "Appleseed John", "nationalNumber": "8885555512", "social_id": null,
> "social_name": null, "social_picture_url": null, "social_url": null,
> "thumbnailPath": ""}, [Function bound dispatchSetState]]
```

I don't know how to access the variables.

Comment: Why you want to declare the state like this const name = useState(route.params.name) and not like the first case ?

Comment: I want to know the behaviour. I have declare the case 3 by mistake. but it was not creating ay warning .

Comment: What useState return is an Array, with 1st element being the variable itself, and 2nd being Function.
When you use it like in the 3rd case, you have to access it like name[0], as it doesn't change the things stored by what you name the variable. Above 2 are just destructing the array.

Comment: You may want to search for how [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) works

Answer (score 1):

The returned value is an array and the 0th index is the state itself and the 1st index is the function for setState.
To access the values, use name[0] and to access the setState function, use name[1].
But this is just against the naming conventions

Answer (score 1):

The case 3 you posted is also a valid expression as it is an array now which consists of two elements the first index 0 being the value itself and the second index 1 being the setState dispatcher. When using case 1 i.e.

```
const [name, setName] = useState(route.params.name);
```

you are destructuring the array. So all the above expressions are valid.

Answer (score 1):

The useState hook returns an array, below I explain in details how you can extract the values and assign them to newly declared variables:

`const x = testThis();`

This assigns x the returned value from calling the function testThis()

`const [x, y, z] = ['Item 1', '123', 'ABC', 'Item 4'];`

This is a way of mapping a list of values to a list of variables.
Test the following for a demonstration.

```
const [x, y, z] = ['Item 1', '123', 'ABC', 'Item 4'];

console.log(x); // Returns "Item 1"
console.log(y); // Returns "123"
console.log(z); // Returns "ABC"
```

Similarly you can split an object. Test the following for a demonstration.

```
const myObject = {
  item1: 'Item 1',
  item2: '123',
  item3: 'ABC',
  item4: 'Item 4'
};

// Here the order doesnt matter because we are splitting the object
// and mapping the variables to keys
const {item1: x, item3: z, item2: y} = myObject;

console.log(x); // Returns "Item 1"
console.log(y); // Returns "123"
console.log(z); // Returns "ABC"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this is not related to the question.